# I'm trying to find a children's poem/nursery rhyme describing a man made of sweets my French teacher used to sing to us, has anyone heard of it?

Tags: histoire, poésie

In grade 3, our French teacher would recite a poem about a man made of sweets and candy. I can't recall much, except that the character had marshmallow shoes and (I think) gingerbread fingers, but it just described how he was made from different desserts in a magical way.

I'm not sure if it's just something she learnt from her family or an actual poem. I've tried searching various translations, asking people learning French and a few french teachers and they haven't heard of it, so I'm not sure if it's something she just picked up, but I've been looking for years without any luck. Just wondering if anyone in here might have heard of it?

Thanks :)

Comment: It's really hard to answer without any text.

Comment: Specifying a country would help too.

Comment: So you recall how sweets and candy were said in the song? Bonbons et sucreries? That might help find it.

Comment: The only thing I know that could be related is the children song "Dame Tartine": https://www.paroles.net/chansons-enfantines/paroles-dame-tartine

Answer (score 1):

The only one i can think of is "Un petit bonhomme".
It's a children song about a man whose mouth is a candy. He has bananas for legs and hold a candy cane.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).